# I am trying to install gameplay game engine ,But encountered an error

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, gameplay3d

I am trying to install **gameplay** game engine on my ubuntuMATE 17.10, following steps [here](https://github.com/gameplay3d/GamePlay/wiki/CMake-Linux-Setup). After `cmake` I type `make` and get errors below:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/samdare/Downloads/extracts/GamePlay-master/external-deps/lib/linux/x86_64/libgameplay-deps.a(btVoronoiSimplexSolver.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/samdare/Downloads/extracts/GamePlay-master/external-deps/lib/linux/x86_64/libgameplay-deps.a(SphereTriangleDetector.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `_ZTV22SphereTriangleDetector' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/samdare/Downloads/extracts/GamePlay-master/external-deps/lib/linux/x86_64/libgameplay-deps.a(trees.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `_length_code' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
samples/browser/CMakeFiles/sample-browser.dir/build.make:745: recipe for target 'samples/browser/sample-browser' failed
make[2]: *** [samples/browser/sample-browser] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:235: recipe for target 'samples/browser/CMakeFiles/sample-browser.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [samples/browser/CMakeFiles/sample-browser.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: The linker recommends "recompile with -fPIC". Have you tried adding that option?

Comment: Strange : The objects will link OK in an rpm based OS, e.g. PCLinuxOS 2017. Ubuntu : Maybe rebuild libgameplay-deps with -fPIC https://github.com/gameplay3d/GamePlay-deps

Answer (score 0):

GamePlay : The linker in Ubuntu 16.04 - amd64 is OK with GamePlay as is.

`sudo apt install g++  cmake libglu1-mesa-dev libogg-dev libopenal-dev libgtk2.0-dev curl lib32z1-dev`

```
git clone https://github.com/gameplay3d/GamePlay.git
cd GamePlay/
./install.sh
mkdir build && cd build/ && cmake .. && make
```

Executable´s created :

```
build/samples/browser/sample-browser
build/samples/racer/sample-racer
build/samples/character/sample-character
build/samples/spaceship/sample-spaceship
```

The Ubuntu 16.04 files seem to work perfect with Ubuntu **17.10** - amd64. My result "build/" → gameplay-build/ was uploaded as `gameplay-build_ubuntu16_amd64.tar.gz` (240MB) . Can be unpacked to any location in /home/*

Link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EIggScf8bGdbBCTMOpjbmKbQcWgs0tpv/view?usp=sharing